# How do I sort by date in a filename when files have different prefixes in bash?

Tags: bash

I have an array of files (with path, path was removed and file name slightly modified for sensitive material), where I want to sort by the date inside the file name (but it sorts together all the prefixes first)

```
A_20160406_161734_083.txt
A_20160406_162033_756.txt
A_20160406_182413_069.txt
A_20160426_093015_846.txt
S_20160406_161741_568.txt
S_20160406_185235_774.txt
S_20160426_093019_852.txt
D__20160407_125904_986.txt
D__20160422_163704_889.txt
D__20160422_173021_513.txt
D__20160422_185627_116.txt
D__20160425_175231_627.txt
D__20160425_210242_615.txt
D__20160426_092631_837.txt
D__20160503_161921_802.txt
D__20160512_122039_138.txt
C_20160406_185205_258.txt
C_20160426_092920_788.txt
```

Here they are sorted by the prefix, how can I instead sort by the date?

Ways I have thought of is saving the names without the prefix, but the problem is getting the prefix back on correctly. (I need to see the prefix as well)

Bonus but not as needed: Separate different dates (not hours) by a '-----'

Comment: Please include what you've tried so far, and what is not working. If you haven't tried anything there's likely no "bonus", as someone else is doing all the work.

Comment: If you remove the double `_`, gnu `sorts` offers everything: `echo "$FILENAMELIST" | sed -r 's/_+/_/g' | sort -t_ -k2`. Here we use `_` as fieldseparator and sort by the second field. The `sed` step takes care of the doubled underscores that are in your example.

Comment: @l'L'l I haven't really tried anything for this problem specifically because I'm pretty new with bash.  I've been doing a lot of string manipulation with this script already and my co-workers want this sort method for readability (which is the point of the whole script I'm writing anyway.  Its a much larger script doing more than just this. 

@LarsFischer, I cannot remove the double `_`. I have to work with the files that are there because I only have read access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

another `sed` solution

```
sed -r 's/(_+)/\1 /' file | sort -k2 | sed 's/_ /_/'
```

separate the first possibly repeated `_` chars, sort, join back.

> `sed -r 's/(_+)/\1 /'` pieces: `(_+)`takes the first (notice no g suffix) longest `_` (since greedy) string assigns to group `\1`  replaces with the first matched group (namely the `_` string) and space.
>
> `sed 's/_ /_/'` replaces the first `_`  (underscore space) match with `_` (underscore only) meaning remove the space.

pipe the sed output to

```
... |  awk -F'_+' 'p!=$2{if(NR>1)print "------";p=$2}1'

A_20160406_161734_083.txt
S_20160406_161741_568.txt
A_20160406_162033_756.txt
A_20160406_182413_069.txt
C_20160406_185205_258.txt
S_20160406_185235_774.txt
------
D__20160407_125904_986.txt
------
D__20160422_163704_889.txt
D__20160422_173021_513.txt
D__20160422_185627_116.txt
------
D__20160425_175231_627.txt
D__20160425_210242_615.txt
------
D__20160426_092631_837.txt
C_20160426_092920_788.txt
A_20160426_093015_846.txt
S_20160426_093019_852.txt
------
D__20160503_161921_802.txt
------
D__20160512_122039_138.txt
```

the whole thing can be converted to gawk as well.

Comment: So this list of file names is stored in an array in a bash script, which originally came from a grep.  Do I just replace file with the variable I'm using?

Comment: The first script expects a file or can be replaced with piped input.  Make sure when you print the variable you have the new lines preserved for example `printf '%s\n' "${file_names[@]}"`

Comment: I'm getting an extra white space in the file names when they get sorted.  I tired deleting the space in the regex `\1` and it somewhat worked, it ended up `-----` separating by prefix AND date. The way you have it sorting is great and the way i need it, I just need to get rid of that whitespace

Comment: actually, `-r` option is not needed there.  I'll update the answer.

Comment: Could you explain how your sed regex works exactly? I'm not too clear on the `\1` part